# Am4 motherboard support for 3000mhz+ memory

Tags: amd-ryzen

I'm looking at building a new ryzen 3rd gen system and I'm a bit confused when it comes to memory. Lots of people say fast memory really helps the ryzen cpus, I saw one article that suggested 3200mhz to 3400mhz for the r 5 3600. The spec on the amd site says 3200 for ram for the ryzen 5 3600. There is plenty of ddr4 ram that supports 3200 or faster, but motherboards seem a bit odd..
I was looking at b450 and an x470 motherboards from gigabyte and their specs suggest you have to overclock to run memory at a rate faster than 2933?

I'm not big into overclocking, should I be able to by a 3600, motherboard and ram and just have the ram run at 3200mhz out the box?

Answer (score 1):

Motherboards default to lower speeds for compatibility reasons.

If you buy higher speed memory then enabling that speed is generally just a matter of changing a bios setting to enable the XMP profile. It is technically an overclock as your going above the base standard, but it is a manufacturer approved overclock and very likely to work just fine.

Motherboard vendors usually have on their website lists of memory they have tested and approved for various speeds/capacities. If you want to be extra sure things work, find the list for your motherboard and then buy something that is on that list.  You'll still need to enable the XMP profile in the bios to get the higher speeds though.